# Changing category IDs for hundreds of products

Tags: magento

I have changed some categories on my magento site recently, and will need to reassign these changes to all the products according to some rules.

1. What is the easiest way to change the categories assigned to products directly via the database, rather than grinding through the admin interface?
2. Also, currently I have this site inside a magento directory as it was not ready for launch. Thus the url www.xyz.com is consumer-facing, but www.xyz.com/magento is not. When I launch, I would like the magento site visible at www.xyz.com. What do I need to do to achieve this? Is it simply a matter of moving all the files from the magento dir into the root, and also changing the paths in admin > config >general > web?

Thanks.
-TM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to update that many products is to export your products to csv and then re-import them again with the category changes that you need to be made.

So goto system->import/export->dataflow:profiles and do an export all products. I would delete any columns you are not updating and import only sku and category ids.

After you are done make your updates, import the csv back in via the Import All Products.

In regards to moving the magento site out of the magento directory. Yes you can just move the files and change the url base paths like you had mentioned. You may need to do this directly in the database from the config_data table. Also make sure to change the rewrite portion of your .htaccess file to reflect the new base path.